# Resetting the cursor position to 0 PHP Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was able to solve the index problem "pos" thanks to this statement "$ request-> get ('pos')"
I was able to recover the correct cursor position in the ajax query but in the controller it is always reset to 0. I did not understand where this problem comes from and how to fix it because it's the first one I use ajax.
I can not really understand how it works
Thanks for your understanding!
here is my new script:
this is my template :new.html.twig

```
{% extends '::layoutv.html.twig' %}
```

{% block stylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% block titre %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

```
<div>
    <h1>
        Insertion des projets
    </h1>
</div>
<!-- BEGIN DISPLAY THE FLASH MESSAGES -->
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('error') %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
        <strong><i class='icon-remove'></i> </strong> {{ flashMessage }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<!--  END DISPLAY THE FLASH MESSAGES -->

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">


        <div class="portlet-body form">
            <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
            <form id="formProject" class="form-horizontal"
                  action="{{ path('new_project') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" }>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Télécharger une image</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="file" name="image">
                        </br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8"  onClick="showWord()">
                                {{ form_row(formProject.texte|raw) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </br>
                </div>
                <div class="controls margin-bottom-30">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn green">Valider</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn yellow">Annuler</button>
                </div>
                {{ form_rest(formProject) }}
            </form>
            <!-- END FORM-->
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function showWord() {
          cursorPos = document.getElementById("formation_minipbundle_project_texte");
          start = cursorPos.selectionStart;
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              async: false,
              data:{'pos' : start},
              url: "{{ path('new_project') }}",
              success: function() {
                  console.log(start);
              }
          });

      }
  </script>
```

{% endblock %}

this my action in the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/create", name="new_project")
 */

public function createAction(Request $request) {

    $project = new Project();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $formProject = $this->createForm('Formation\MiniPBundle\Form\ProjectType', $project);
    $formProject->handleRequest($request);
    if ($formProject->isValid()) {
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
          //  $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
         //   $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file_name);
            header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            $string=$formProject->get('texte')->getData();
            $text= filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //Supprimer les balises.

            $font = 15;

            $width = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string);

            $height = imagefontheight($font) ;

            switch (strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))){
                case "jpg" :
                    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
                    break;
                case "gif" :
                    $im = imagecreatefromgif($file_name);
                    break;
                case "png" :
                    $im = imagecreatefrompng($file_name);
                    break;
                case "bmp":
                    $im = imagecreatefrombmp($file_name);
                    break;

                default :
                    trigger_error("Error Bad Extention");
                    exit();
                    break;
            }
            $position=intval($request->get('pos'));
            $y = imagesy($im) - $height;
            $textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255,255);
            /*----------------------------------------*/
           imagestring($im, $font, $position, $y, $text, $textColor);
            $project->setLogo($file_name);
            $em->persist($project);
            $em->flush();
            imagejpeg($im);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('FormationMiniPBundle:Project:new.html.twig', array(
                'project' => $project,
                'request'=> $request->request->get('pos'),
                'formProject' => $formProject->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(start)`?

Comment: console.log(start) returns an integer that is the cursor position in the textarea   @AlexanderHolman

Comment: Have you tried `$_GET['pos']`??

Comment: And for the backend are you using any framework, e.g. laravel? If not, can we get some information around `$request` and it's `get` method?

Comment: Yes I mean `$_POST['pos']`

Comment: i tried    $position= $_POST["pos"] but it returns     Notice: Undefined index: pos   @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: you've quite a few unclosed questions there.

Comment: It could be bad naming so 'get the query item pos' .

Comment: Then you need to post more info about what you've inside the controller

Comment: I followed some tutorials because this is the first time I use ajax, I used the element pos of data returned by the action ajax  @ZakariaAcharki  i will edit my publication with a  complete controller

Comment: your code is unreachable if you send just `{'pos' : start}``, it will never pass the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` condition

Comment: so how can i how can I solve this problem @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: I'm going to edit my post here because I can not post more questions on this site @Zakaria Acharki

Comment: Why you can't @user10269341 ?!!

Comment: I do not know, maybe this is one of the rules of this site because the last time I had the same case. I was able to ask a question after 2 days.
in any case I have updated my publication on this page you find the new code if you want to give me help and I will be grateful!   @ Zakaria Acharki

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't tell us what PHP Framework are you using, in Plain PHP you should have the POST data on the Variables

$_POST['pos']
or
$_REQUEST['pos']

But on your Javascript code, you are printing the start on the success of the ajax, that is after the value is sent to the server and return... so, since there is a significant delay, that means the start variable may be null before the ajax.

Try to use the console.log(start) right after this line:

start = cursorPos.selectionStart;
console.log(start);

And Before the ajax is made, because if in that point is null, you will get null on the server.

Comment: I followed what you told me but I encountered the same problem, it is always reinitialized to 0. So how can do to fix this problem thanks!